# Reducing an Array of Objects when there is only one Element in the Array

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have this array `[{num:1}, {num:2}, {num:3}]`.  I can do the following -

```
[{num:1}, {num:2}, {num:3}].reduce((a, b) => a.num === undefined? a + b.num : a.num + b.num)
```

I get "6", great!  However if my array only has one element (say I'm dynamically filling my array using a loop and need to reduce during each iteration) something like `[{num:1}]` and do the same -

```
[{num:1}].reduce((a, b) => a.num === undefined? a + b.num : a.num + b.num)
```

I get "{num: 1}" which makes sense (if there is only one element return that element).

So is there any way I can use the `reduce` function and get the "correct" answer (i.e. "1") for the above answer.

I realise I *could* just create my own function (looping round the array, summing as I go and return the total) but I am interested to see if it is possible to use the reduce function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can provide an initial value of `0`:

```
array.reduce(
  (a, b) => a + b.num,
  0 // <-- initial value
);
```

It will work for empty arrays too (returning `0`).

Comment: Annoyingly simple, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two answers:

1)

```
[{ num: 6 }].reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b.num; }, 0);
// note the starting-value for A, passed into reduce.
```

2)

```
[{ num: 6 }].map(el => el.num).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
// I should still pass the starting-value,
// but here I've mapped all of the elements first,
// into the same type that the reduce is expecting,
// thus simplifying the reduce to be a simple add function
```

Comment: I like the out-of-the-box thinking of the `map` answer.